# Flink - Failed to recover from a checkpoint

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb, stream-processing

I'm running my cluster on kubernetes with a single jobmanager and 2 taskmanagers.
I tested the mechanism of checkpoint by killing one of the taskmanager pods while the job is running.
I got the following exceptions on the jobmanager and the restarted taskmanager:

Jobmanager exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:195)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:881)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for WindowOperator_54288f79b169ee3e8cb1feb33bbad4c3_(1/8) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:135)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Caught unexpected exception.
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:520)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:291)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /rocksdb/job_0a1a61f5cbecc09fbaef1257b3392b3a_op_WindowOperator_54288f79b169ee3e8cb1feb33bbad4c3__1_8__uuid_8b95eb2f-f6cf-4c35-8274-a9055376163d/db/000021.sst -> /rocksdb/job_0a1a61f5cbecc09fbaef1257b3392b3a_op_WindowOperator_54288f79b169ee3e8cb1feb33bbad4c3__1_8__uuid_8b95eb2f-f6cf-4c35-8274-a9055376163d/f1a97117-3810-400e-85ca-6e8c998a5ed4/000021.sst
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:476)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1086)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreInstanceDirectoryFromPath(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreFromLocalState(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreFromRemoteState(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreWithoutRescaling(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restore(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:148)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:270)
    ... 12 more
```

Taskmanager exception:

```
2020-01-13 09:26:01,943 ERROR org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder  - Caught unexpected exception.
org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to sanitize XML document destined for handler class org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.sanitizeXmlDocument(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:317)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1554)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1272)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4325)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4272)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4266)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:834)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.listPrefix(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:484)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.access$000(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem$1.<init>(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:271)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.listStatus(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:258)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.hadoop.HadoopFileSystem.listStatus(HadoopFileSystem.java:157)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.listStatus(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreInstanceDirectoryFromPath(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreFromLocalState(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreFromRemoteState(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreWithoutRescaling(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restore(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:148)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:520)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:291)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:881)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.abortIfNeeded(SdkFilterInputStream.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:210)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.sanitizeXmlDocument(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:191)
    ... 44 more
2020-01-13 09:26:01,944 WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure  - Exception while restoring keyed state backend for WindowOperator_54288f79b169ee3e8cb1feb33bbad4c3_(7/8) from alternative (1/1), will retry while more alternatives are available.
org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Caught unexpected exception.
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:520)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:291)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:881)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to sanitize XML document destined for handler class org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.sanitizeXmlDocument(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:317)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1554)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1272)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4325)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4272)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4266)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:834)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.listPrefix(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:484)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.access$000(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem$1.<init>(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:271)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.listStatus(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:258)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.hadoop.HadoopFileSystem.listStatus(HadoopFileSystem.java:157)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.listStatus(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreInstanceDirectoryFromPath(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreFromLocalState(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreFromRemoteState(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restoreWithoutRescaling(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.restore(RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java:148)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:270)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.abortIfNeeded(SdkFilterInputStream.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:210)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.sanitizeXmlDocument(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:191)
    ... 44 more
```

When I tried to restore from a savepoint, everything works as expected.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From our experience, one possible cause could be you come across below exception first:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to sanitize XML document destined for handler class org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
```

Then the procedure to restore rocksdb state-backend would be interrupted leading to file `/rocksdb/job_0a1a61f5cbecc09fbaef1257b3392b3a_op_WindowOperator_54288f79b169ee3e8cb1feb33bbad4c3__1_8__uuid_8b95eb2f-f6cf-4c35-8274-a9055376163d/f1a97117-3810-400e-85ca-6e8c998a5ed4/000021.sst` deleted in https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/390926e61aeb69837c70a024ad6e7ff02eccdf2d/flink-state-backends/flink-statebackend-rocksdb/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/contrib/streaming/state/restore/RocksDBIncrementalRestoreOperation.java#L197

That's why you found the `NoSuchFileException`.